# how to add two id's for jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

[JSfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/o1hdh8rw/7/)

Here I am restricting zero at first position and I restricted that for a single field using it's id. Now I want to restrict the same for two fields. How can I achieve that functionality in a single function.

```
$('input#abc#xyz').keypress(function(e){ 
   if (this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 48 ){
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Instead of using IDs, you can use a common class and use this as selector.

Comment: There must be dupes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#upload_link,#upload_link2,#upload_link3").each(function(){
  $(this).upload({
    //whateveryouwant
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use comma **,** to give [multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('#abc,#xyz').keypress(function(e){ 
   if (this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 48 ){
      return false;
   }
});
```